# Mongodb Morphia aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm having trouble creating aggregation in Morphia, the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.1/guides/aggregation/) is really not clear. This is the original query:

```
db.collection('events').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "identifier": {
        $in: [
          userId1, userId2
        ]
      },
      $or: [
        {
          "info.name": "messageType",
          "info.value": "Push",
          "timestamp": {
            $gte: newDate("2015-04-27T19:53:13.912Z"),
            $lte: newDate("2015-08-27T19:53:13.912Z")
          }
        }
      ]
    }{
      $unwind: "$info"
    },
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          {
            "info.name": "messageType",
            "info.value": "Push"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]);
```

The only example in their docs was using out and there's some example [here](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation/ZipCodeDataSetTest.java) but I couldn't make it to work.

I didn't even made it past the first match, here's what I have:

```
    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
            ids.add("199941");
            ids.add("199951");
    Query<Event> q = ads.getQueryFactory().createQuery(ads);
    q.and(q.criteria("identifier").in(ids));
    AggregationPipeline pipeline = ads.createAggregation(Event.class).match(q);
Iterator<Event> iterator =  pipeline.aggregate(Event.class);
```

Some help or guidance and how to start with the query or how it works will be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the query for the [**`match()`**](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation/AggregationTest.java) pipeline by breaking your code down into manageable pieces that will be easy to follow. So let's start
with the query to match the identifier field, you have done the great so far. We need to then combine with the [**`$or`**](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#filter) part of the query.

Carrying on from where you left, create the full query as:

```
Query<Event> q = ads.getQueryFactory().createQuery(ads);
Criteria[] arrayA = {
    q.criteria("info.name").equal("messageType"), 
    q.criteria("info.value").equal("Push"),
    q.field("timestamp").greaterThan(start);
    q.field("timestamp").lessThan(end);
};

Criteria[] arrayB = {
    q.criteria("info.name").equal("messageType"), 
    q.criteria("info.value").equal("Push")  
};

q.and(
    q.criteria("identifier").in(ids),
    q.or(arrayA)
);

Query<Event> query = ads.getQueryFactory().createQuery(ads);
query.or(arrayB);

AggregationPipeline pipeline = ads.createAggregation(Event.class)
                                  .match(q)
                                  .unwind("info")
                                  .match(query);
Iterator<Event> iterator =  pipeline.aggregate(Event.class);
```

The above is untested but will guide you somewhere closer home, so make some necessary adjustments where appropriate. For some references, the following SO questions may give you some pointers:

1. [Complex AND-OR query in Morphia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284116/complex-and-or-query-in-morphia)
2. [Morphia query with or operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873969/morphia-query-with-or-operator)

and of course the **[AggregationTest.java](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation/AggregationTest.java)** Github page

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to create the query. I have one question is the 'q' variable in the arrayB  declaration 'q.criteria' should be replaced with 'query.criteria'. If not why?